# sed replace a word at a line which begins with a specific pattern using

Tags: sed

How can I replace a word at a line which begins with a specific pattern on FreeBSD?
Consider the following file contents:

```
this is to test 
that was for test
```

I want to replace "test" at the line which begins with "this".

Answer (score 19):

In order to perform a replacement for lines starting with `this`, say:

```
$ sed '/^this/ s/test/something/' inputfile
this is to something 
that was for test
```

This would replace the word `test` with `something` on lines starting with `this`.

If you want to replace all instances of `test` on the matching lines, supply the `g` option to sed:

```
sed '/^this/ s/test/something/g' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

To make the changes in-place, use the below command:

```
sed -i '/^this/ s/test/something/g' inputfile;
```