# Deleting a string upto first occurrence of right bracket

Tags: regex, sed, replace, posix

I have a file that looks like:

```sh
[----------] 7 tests from RouteGenSetup
[ RUN      ] RouteGenSetup.AcceptTATTest
[2021-03-08 22:55:53.937] [info] TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 1.1 -> 2.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
[2021-03-08 22:55:53.937] [info] TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 1.1 -> 5.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
[2021-03-08 22:55:53.937] [info] TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 6.1 -> 7.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
[       OK ] RouteGenSetup.AcceptTATTest (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] RouteGenSetup.BlockLinksTest
[2021-03-08 22:55:53.937] [error] TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 1.1 -> 2.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
[2021-03-08 22:55:53.938] [error] TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 1.1 -> 5.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
```

I want to get rid of the date and time stamp (e.g., `[2021-03-08 22:55:53.937]`). To do so, I tried using the following `sed` command:

```sh
sed -i '/^\[2021-/s/^.*\]\ //1' output.txt
```

However, the `[info]` or `[error]` bracket to the right of the time stamp also gets deleted:

```sh
[----------] 7 tests from RouteGenSetup
[ RUN      ] RouteGenSetup.AcceptTATTest
TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 1.1 -> 2.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 1.1 -> 5.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 6.1 -> 7.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
[       OK ] RouteGenSetup.AcceptTATTest (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] RouteGenSetup.BlockLinksTest
TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 1.1 -> 2.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 1.1 -> 5.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
```

When I try

```sh
sed -i '/^\[2021/s/[^\]]*//' output.txt
```

the first open bracket deletes instead of the first closed bracket:

```sh
[----------] 7 tests from RouteGenSetup
[ RUN      ] RouteGenSetup.AcceptTATTest
2021-03-08 22:55:53.937] [info] TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 1.1 -> 2.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
2021-03-08 22:55:53.937] [info] TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 1.1 -> 5.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
2021-03-08 22:55:53.937] [info] TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 6.1 -> 7.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
[       OK ] RouteGenSetup.AcceptTATTest (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] RouteGenSetup.BlockLinksTest
2021-03-08 22:55:53.937] [error] TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 1.1 -> 2.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
2021-03-08 22:55:53.938] [error] TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 1.1 -> 5.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
```

And trying

```sh
sed -i '/^\[2021/s/^[^\]]*\]//' output.txt
```

produces no change. I'm not sure how to fix this. I tried a number of things recommended in similar posts but no luck.

**NOTE**: This is not a duplicate of [sed - regex square brackets detection in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684551/sed-regex-square-brackets-detection-in-linux) because here, the problem is different: only match a substring between the start of string and the first `]` + space if the line starts with a certain prefix.

[sed replace a word at a line which begins with a specific pattern using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694162/sed-replace-a-word-at-a-line-which-begins-with-a-specific-pattern-using) does not explain how to get the lines that start with a special character and then match the string from start till the first `]` + space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```sh
sed -i '/^\[2021-/s/^[^]]*] //' file
```

Here,

- `/^\[2021-/` - finds lines that start with `[2021-`
- `s/^[^]]*] //` - matches any zero or more chars other than `]` from the start of the string till the first `]` and then a space and removes these matches (since the RHS is empty).

Note `[^]]` is a *negated bracket expression* that matches any char but `]`. Since bracket expressions do not support regex escape sequences, `]` needs to be the first char in the bracket expression, you cannot use `\]` anwhere in a bracket expression.

See [an online demo](https://ideone.com/Phguvx):

```sh
s='[----------] 7 tests from RouteGenSetup
[ RUN      ] RouteGenSetup.AcceptTATTest
[2021-03-08 22:55:53.937] [info] TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 1.1 -> 2.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
[2021-03-08 22:55:53.937] [info] TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 1.1 -> 5.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
[2021-03-08 22:55:53.937] [info] TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 6.1 -> 7.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
[       OK ] RouteGenSetup.AcceptTATTest (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] RouteGenSetup.BlockLinksTest
[2021-03-08 22:55:53.937] [error] TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 1.1 -> 2.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
[2021-03-08 22:55:53.938] [error] TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 1.1 -> 5.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR'
sed '/^\[2021-/s/^[^]]*] //' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```sh
[----------] 7 tests from RouteGenSetup
[ RUN      ] RouteGenSetup.AcceptTATTest
[info] TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 1.1 -> 2.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
[info] TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 1.1 -> 5.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
[info] TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 6.1 -> 7.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
[       OK ] RouteGenSetup.AcceptTATTest (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] RouteGenSetup.BlockLinksTest
[error] TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 1.1 -> 2.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
[error] TimeSlotAssignmentTable::LogTATRow(Add): 1.1 -> 5.1, rounds: LLLLLL, pattern: TR
```